# Address suggestions by google maps

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-api

Does somebody know if there is any way to reproduce an ajax suggestion box like http://maps.google.com/ have in my webpage using the google maps api?

The idea would be for example if somebody writes down "15 Avenue" a list of suggestions:

"15 Avenue of the Americas, New York, NY, United States"

"15 Avenue of the Stars, Los Angeles, CA, United States"

Etc

Just a yes no qustion =)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Look at the geocode response for "15 Avenue"...

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=15+Avenue&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=15%20Avenue&sensor=false)

You get a list of possible results that you can put in a dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

There is an API example from Google.

Make sure you load the `places` library:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places">
</script>
```

Next your javascript:

```
var autocomplete;
function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('autocomplete'),
        { types: ['geocode'] }
    );
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

With HTML

```
<div><input id="autocomplete" type="text"></div>
```

Also see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 1):

I found this on another answer on stackoverflow. This page shows how to provide autocomplete choices using google maps/geocoding.

http://tech.cibul.net/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/